# WPF - Why is my property not being updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here's some code:

```
<ListBox
    MaxWidth="468"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Visitors, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType={x:Type ListBoxItem}>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding VisitorSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

I need `Visitors` to be updated (at the source) whenever a visitor is selected.  For some reason, What I have doesn't work.  I'm racking my brain, but I can't think of a way around this.  Ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, I accidentally had a duplicated property in there, which I removed.  Also, let me clarify something: `VisitorSelected` IS getting updated.  However it's not doing me much good, because I need to be notified in the view model containing `Visitors` - not where `VisitorSelected` is defined.  I hope this makes sense

Comment: How come there are two `ItemContainerStyle` assignments? One by `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxContainerStyle}"` and other by `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>`?

Comment: You are using two-way binding on Visitors meaning any changes to Visitors will be reflected in the ListBox and any changes to the collection in the ListBox will update Visitors. However, the collection's number of elements doesn't change when an item is selected. No items are added or removed when an item is selected. So, Visitors doesn't get updated. Seems like VisitorSelected should get updated though.

Comment: You can raise property changed notification from where `VisitorSelected` is declared, whenever `VisitorSelected` is changed and your ViewModel can listen to those events and respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding an `Action` parameter to the visitor item type, then calling that when `VisitorSelected` is set.  The `Action` is passed in by the view model.